# Python Dictionary and List in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

my code is like this

```
for dict_item in data:
    MILLISECONDS = dict_item['Start_Time'].split('(')[1][:-2]
    mydict = {'Cinema_Name':dict_item['Cinema_Name'],
              'Movie_Time':datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(MILLISECONDS)/1000.0).strftime('%B-%d-%Y %I:%M %p'),
ListOfJson.append(mydict)
```

output is this

```
 {
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
    "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 06:20 PM"
},
{
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
    "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 09:15 PM"
},
{
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
    "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 11:30 AM"
},
{
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
    "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 02:25 PM"
}
```

but i want an output that would merge all with the came Cinema_Name and put their time in a list. somethin like this

```
{
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3"
    "Movie_Time": " ["October-13-2018 06:20 PM","October-13-2018 09:15 PM"]
},
{
    "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6"
    "Movie_Time: ["October-12-2018 11:30 AM" ,"October-12-2018 02:25 PM"]
```

Is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `dict` and create your list. No need fancy code or `List` parsing. Just , 2 lines of code: `[obj["Movie_Time"] for obj in myDict if obj["Cinema_Name"] == "Cinema 3"]` and another one for the `Cinema 6` as below.

```
myDict = [
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
        "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 06:20 PM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
        "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 09:15 PM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
        "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 11:30 AM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
        "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 02:25 PM"
    }
]

ListOfJson = [
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
        "Movie_Time": [obj["Movie_Time"] for obj in myDict if obj["Cinema_Name"] == "Cinema 3"]
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
        "Movie_Time": [obj["Movie_Time"] for obj in myDict if obj["Cinema_Name"] == "Cinema 6"]
    }
]

print(ListOfJson)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    'Cinema_Name': 'Cinema 3',
    'Movie_Time': [
      'October-13-2018 06:20 PM',
      'October-13-2018 09:15 PM'
    ]
  },
  {
    'Cinema_Name': 'Cinema 6',
    'Movie_Time': [
      'October-12-2018 11:30 AM',
      'October-12-2018 02:25 PM'
    ]
  }
]
```

The difference between my solution and the one of @blhsing is that:
Mine start only 3 processes in same time, that accelerate the speed.
[image]

The solution of @blhsing has 5 processes on a 2 childs which considerably slow down your speed.
[image]

Comment: @khel : If you have any question please let me know!

Comment: what if i have more cinemas like cinema 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, i would add more If statements? hmm

Comment: If you would use more than what you show, I would use an array for 10 and less, for 100 it would be even better than it, but it is a new requirement and if you need more than 2 object, it is a duplicate question. So that was the best solution for 2 objects... at least just make a upvote or a thanks lol, it is ok to pimp the reput of your friend but look the other answers. They make sens as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict to keep track of the `Movie_Time` list for the first entry of a new `Cinema_Name` so that the subsequent entries of the same `Cinema_Name` can be appended to the same list:

```
ListOfJson = [
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
        "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 06:20 PM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 3",
        "Movie_Time": "October-13-2018 09:15 PM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
        "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 11:30 AM"
    },
    {
        "Cinema_Name": "Cinema 6",
        "Movie_Time": "October-12-2018 02:25 PM"
    }
]
l = []
index = {}
for d in ListOfJson:
    if d['Cinema_Name'] in index:
        index[d['Cinema_Name']].append(d['Movie_Time'])
    else:
        index[d['Cinema_Name']] = d['Movie_Time'] = [d['Movie_Time']]
        l.append(d)
print(l)
```

With your sample input, `l` would become:

`[{'Cinema_Name': 'Cinema 3', 'Movie_Time': ['October-13-2018 06:20 PM', 'October-13-2018 09:15 PM']}, {'Cinema_Name': 'Cinema 6', 'Movie_Time': ['October-12-2018 11:30 AM', 'October-12-2018 02:25 PM']}]`

Comment: It looks like `ListOfJson` and `data` are different in OP's example.  (OP has `for d in data`, and `ListOfJson` is what you are calling `l`.)

Comment: `ListOfJson` is what the OP calls the output, and I'm using the OP's output as input as that's what the OP wants the desired output to transform from. I've updated my answer with `ListOfJson`'s definition for clarity.

Comment: Ok.  I read it as OP didn't want to transform current output, but wanted to replace current code with something that would yield the desired output without the intermediary step.  I see why you did it this way - nice answer.

Comment: @blhsing you almost got it right but the problem now is in Else Statement, it continously add the list of Cinema_Time repeatedly. like this "Movie_Time": [
            [
                "October-12-2018 07:15 PM",
                "October-13-2018 07:45 PM"
            ],
            [
                "October-12-2018 07:15 PM",
                "October-13-2018 07:45 PM"
            ]

Comment: Is the `Dict` to `List` conversion can be avoided ? ;)

Comment: @blhsing thank you!! you saved my day today!! thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporal dict to index cinemas while iterating the list and be able to append movie times:

```
temp_dict = {}
for dict_item in data:
    movie_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(MILLISECONDS)/1000.0).strftime('%B-%d-%Y %I:%M %p')
    if dict_item['Cinema_Name'] not in temp_dict:
        temp_dict[dict_item['Cinema_Name']] = {
            'Cinema_Name':dict_item['Cinema_Name'],
            'Movie_Time': []
        }
    temp_dict[dict_item['Cinema_Name']]['Movie_Time'].append(movie_time)

ListOfJson = list(temp_dict.values())
```